# Have problems with testing my project by maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: unit-testing, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I wrote my maven project in Netbeans.I wrote tests for my project (dao,service..). All tests are right, but when I build or test my project maven shows there are no tests to compile.I'm using maven-surefire-plugin, so include it to the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.10</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>                          
                   </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
```

I think something wrong with surefire-plugin..

Thats:

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Employeers 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[aspectj:compile]

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 4 resources

[compiler:compile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[aspectj:test-compile]

[resources:testResources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

[compiler:testCompile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[surefire:test]
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\surefire-reports
Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file C:\Users\?????????????\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\surefire\surefirebooter472050683580306804.jar

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[war:war]
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [Employeers] in [C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\Employeers-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\src\main\webapp]
Webapp assembled in [590 msecs]
Building war: C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\Employees.war
Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.258s
Finished at: Fri Jul 27 19:47:07 EEST 2012
Final Memory: 6M/16M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username with cyrillic characters might be involved.

While the plugin initially states the following directory:

```
C:\Users\Администратор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\surefire-reports
```

it later refers to it as the following (note the question marks):

```
C:\Users\?????????????\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Employeers\target\surefire\surefirebooter472050683580306804.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Orique a lot.Are there any posible solutions without changing directory?

Comment: Hard to tell. Looks like an encoding issue. Did you set UTF-8 as the default encoding for your project? [link](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning). Please post pom.xml so maybe others can help.

Comment: UTF-8 is setted as the default

Answer (score 1):

That's my pom:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Employeers</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Employeers</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.springframework.roo-version>1.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.roo-version>

  </properties>

    <dependencies>

       <!--              SERVLET                                  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--                                               -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--   Hibernate                                     -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Support of transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
        </exclusions>   
        </dependency>

        <!--                       ROO                    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.roo-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--                        Aspectj                 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--                        LOGGING                 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

             <!--                            @Inject                              -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

            <!--                            TEST                                 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>     

             <!---->    
         <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--                        Security                    -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--                   Spring mvc                          -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>Employees</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!--
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                        -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>

                   </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>

          </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
                <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
                <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
                        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
                        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
                        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/</url>
                        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <id>junit_4</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[junit_4]</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```